# Do you need to synchronized reading from HashMap?

Tags: concurrency, hashmap, synchronization

I have a `java.util.HashMap` object. I guarantee that writing to `HashMap` is done by single dedicated thread. However, reading from the same `HashMap` object can be done from more that one thread at the time. Can I run in any troubles with such implementation?

Comment: For multithreaded programs always use java.util.ConcurrentHashMap. Even during reading values from HashMap, it uses some internal fields which will be shared among the writer and reader threads, which may lead to read of an inconsistent state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can run into big troubles with such an implementation!

Adding a value to the HashMap is not an atomic operation. So if you read the map from another thread you might see an inconsistent state when another thread is adding a value at the same time. This will lead to randomly unexpected behavior or exceptions when running your code. Furthermore, without synchronization it is not guaranteed when updated variables become visible to other threads.

So as 11thdimenstion said in the comment of your question you should really use `ConcurrentHashMap` for your purposes or properly synchronize your read **and** write access to the map.

Comment: Thanks I ended up using ConcurentHashMap.